# Why does a simple Spring boot/integration example cause "Requested bean is currently in creation"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a pretty minimal example, that causes an error.
Note that the packages seem to matter, putting all classes in the same package works.

Basically, I create a DirectChannel, have a @Component which gets auto wired with it, and a ServiceActivator in the @Configuration which refers to the same channel.

As far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything special or uncommon, so mayby this is a bug?

Full example code underneath, pay attention to the packages ('test' and 'test.config')

Thanks!

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>my.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>Circularity</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot integration starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

IntegrationConfiguration.java

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;

@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    DirectChannel myChannel() {

        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
    public MessageHandler stdoutMessageHandler() {

        return m -> System.out.println(m.toString());
    }

}
```

SomeComponent.java

```
package test.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    public SomeComponent(MessageChannel myChannel) {
        // Pretend I store the MessageChannel so I can send something to it later.
        // But this is not needed to cause the issue!
    }

}
```

CircularApp.java

```
package test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CircularApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(CircularApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

And on popular request, a stack trace :)
Note that this is on a different machine, with the code from this question quickly copy pasted.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.7.RELEASE)

2017-10-10 20:14:26.537  INFO 1796 --- [           main] test.CircularApp                         : Starting CircularApp on ORCA with PID 1796 (C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes started by Jeroen in C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity)
2017-10-10 20:14:26.539  INFO 1796 --- [           main] test.CircularApp                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-10 20:14:26.578  INFO 1796 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@7dc222ae: startup date [Tue Oct 10 20:14:26 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-10 20:14:26.790  INFO 1796 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2017-10-10 20:14:26.877  INFO 1796 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2017-10-10 20:14:26.879  INFO 1796 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2017-10-10 20:14:26.960  INFO 1796 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-10-10 20:14:26.963  INFO 1796 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [java.util.Properties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-10-10 20:14:27.028  WARN 1796 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someComponent' defined in file [C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes\test\config\SomeComponent.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes\test\IntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'myChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2017-10-10 20:14:27.034  INFO 1796 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-10 20:14:27.039 ERROR 1796 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'someComponent' defined in file [C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes\test\config\SomeComponent.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes\test\IntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'myChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at test.CircularApp.main(CircularApp.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'integrationConfiguration' defined in file [C:\Storage\workspace\Circularity\target\classes\test\IntegrationConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'myChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.core.DestinationResolutionException: A bean definition with name 'myChannel' exists, but failed to be created; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.createEndpoint(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcess(AbstractMethodAnnotationPostProcessor.java:220) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.processAnnotationTypeOnMethod(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor$1.doWith(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:200) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(MessagingAnnotationPostProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myChannel': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:347) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver.resolveDestination(BeanFactoryChannelResolver.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
public SomeComponent(MessageChannel myChannel) {
    // Pretend I will send something to the channel.
}
```

You can't start sending messages until the application context is fully built; sending a message from a constructor is obviously before that.

Comment: Right, updated the question to better reflect my case :) In the bigger code it's derived from, the constructor just stores the MessageChannel for later use. Also note that using a setter instead has exactly the same effect, and that this code as posted fails, even though it doesn't actually use the MessageChannel in the constructor.

Comment: A stack trace is added! :)

Comment: I am not sure why that's happening, but you can delete the `myChannel` `@Bean` and the framework will create a `DirectChannel` automatically with that name.

Comment: Hmm, sadly it doesn't, at least not so it can be autowired into SomeComponent, the result is: "Parameter 0 of constructor in test.config.SomeComponent required a single bean, but 2 were found:
 - nullChannel: defined in null
 - errorChannel: defined in null"

Comment: What seems to work as a temporary workaround is to not autoscan SomeComponent  (Remove \@Component annotation), and instead instantiate it from IntegrationConfiguration, using a \@Bean annotation.